# On an Array, length is pre-calculated or calculated everytime through iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, programming-languages

Sample data

arrayList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

> arrayList.length is 5

When I do `arrayList.length` , what is the action behind the scene ?

- arrayList is iterated and length is returned

OR

- length is pre-calculated at Data Structure being used for Array

---

PS: I am using JavaScript, but would like to know about an in general behaviour across various languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript you can change the length of an array.  But `array.length` is an attribute.  It is not "computed" each time by counting elements.

Note that when you assign a new value to an array's length attribute, the runtime system will take care of growing or shrinking the array for you.

> I would like to know about an in general behavior across various languages.

You can't generalize:

- Some languages allow you to change the size of an array; for example Python, Ruby, and so on.  This is not necessarily done by assigning to a length or size attribute.

  - In Python for example, the length of an array (or a list) is not an attribute.  It is the value returned by the `len` function.  You change a Python array size by adding and removing elements.
  - In Ruby, the length of an array is a read-only attribute.
- Other languages do not allow the length on a primitive array to be changed; for example Java, Ada and so on.
- And for some languages (C, BCPL) an array's length is not part of its runtime value.  (Indeed, in BCPL arrays are not even a type.) So that means that an application can't access the array's length.  It has to be handled as a separate variable, or deduced via (say) a zero termination convention.  (The latter implies that you compute the array's notional length by iteration, but you need to worry about overrun.)

Answer (score 2):

Speaking about JS, the length of the array is stored as an object property. So it is readily available. It doesn't iterate through the array every time you do `array.length`

N.B (supposed to be a comment but I lack reputation for that)